# document.write is stalling the rest of my Javascript, solutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

So my journey with this issue started when I initially was trying to asynchronously load a reddit social media widget. If you open the URL in the `getScript` parameter below you'll notice that this does a direct `document.write`. If I didn't didn't capture that code, it would have rewritten the entire document when I run `.getScript`.

```
var content = '';
document.write = function(s) {
    content += s;
};

$.getScript('http://www.reddit.com/domain/skattertech.com/new/.embed?limit=4&amp;t=all&amp;sort=new&amp;style=off', function(){
    $('body').append(content);
});
```

The code above works, but despite the default async nature of `.getScript`, pairing it up with `document.write` causes my entire JS file to halt from running until it has the data to write. IF reddit's server is slow or doesn't respond, the rest of my other widgets won't load.

Is there any simple workarounds to solve this? Is it possible to fetch that script as a string to then split and pop the `document.write` wrapper off? If the only thing left is the HTML, I can easy write that in at anytime without affecting the rest of my script right?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening. jQuery.getScript creates a <script> element in <head> and doesn't use document.write? Unless you're not using jQuery?

Comment: oh right, I just saw the actual script that is being loaded...

Comment: Sorry, what is document.write = function(s) { content += s; } doing?

Comment: @Pandincus Overriding the document.write function.

Comment: AndreKR is correct, it is a trick to prevent document.write in the reddit widget from rewriting the entire DOM. Simply trying a way to prevent stalling from occurring if there's a delay from `.getScript`. This is so frustrating ugghh! :(

Comment: Isn't messing with host objects bad?

Comment: It is, he could set it back to the original function inside the $.getScript callback, but there probably isn't much point.

Answer (score 1):

Sahas, with your clever trick of overriding the document.write function, I don't see any delay at all in executing the following script:

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write = function(s) {
            $("body").append(s);
        };
        $(function() {
            $.getScript('http://www.reddit.com/domain/skattertech.com/new/.embed?limit=4&amp;t=all&amp;sort=new&amp;style=off');
            $("#testDiv").fadeIn('slow');
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #testDiv
        {
            background-color: #0c0c0c;
            color: #fff;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is a test</p>
    <div id="testDiv">
        <p>This is a test.</p>
        <p>This div won't be shown until after $.getScript() executes.</p>
        <p>Blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

I executed it several times and, even if reddit was slow to respond, my

```
$("#testDiv").fadeIn('slow');
```

code executed well before reddit was finished sending my page back the script.

Am I missing the problem?

Comment: I have a Facebook Activity Feed placed before this guy. After the Reddit widget, I have social media buttons such as a Like button, StumbleUpon, Tweet This, Digg This, etc. Unfortunately, even without having to use Yslow, I can see visually see that most other widgets don't even begin loading until "waiting for reddit.com" is complete. The Twitter Button and Like button heavily affected as well http://jsfiddle.net/Kr9zS/6/ Can you look at my sample code and offer any suggestions or optimizations?

Comment: Even looking at your jsfiddle example, the social media buttons load before the Reddit widget fills with content. I'm using Chrome 8. Is it a browser thing?

Comment: As box9 said, I copied your jsfiddle example into a .html file and ran it, making sure your widgetLoader() code was executed inside a $(function() { }); statement, thus ensuring the DOM was first loaded. It ran fine -- the reddit content was loaded AFTER the other widgets loaded, actually. I'm using Chrome 9 ... what browser are you using, Sahas?